# How can I get name of Kids as result if I search on one of their Parents using JPA in Java?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I was thinking to use `@JoinTable` to be able ***displaying the name of kid when I search on his parent*** but a little struggling with it.

**The program stores kids and one of their parents (or both) and when I search the name of the parent the program should display the name of kid (or kids).**

Two interfaces needed:

- name of parents and kids (name of parent is unique, so in case if it already exists then we just insert the name of the kid (and its parent_id)
- **when I search on the name of the parent the program displays his/her kid (or kids).**
- PARENTS table:

```sql
ID (PK, NN, AI, int)            
NAME (NN, String)
```

- KIDS table:

```sql
ID (PK, NN, AI, int)            
NEV (NN, String)            
PARENTS_ID (NN, int)
```

The program should use a FK and OneToMany, ManyToOne connection which uses **search and save**.

I would welcome any suggestions about what is the best practice to finish the code.

**Parents.java**

```
@Entity 
public class Parents {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long Id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parents") 
    private List<Kids> kids;
    // constructor + getters & setters
```

**Kids.java**

```
@Entity
public class Kids {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long Id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parents_id")
    @NotNull
    private Parents parents;

    public Kids() {
    }

    public Kids(String firstName, String lastName, Parents parents) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.parents = parents;
    }
    // getters & setters
```

**data.sql**

```sql
INSERT INTO Parents (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Viz','Elek');
INSERT INTO Parents (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Locsolok','Anna');
INSERT INTO Parents (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Kezmuves','Kelemen');
INSERT INTO Kids (first_name, last_name, parents_id) VALUES ('Nagy','Zolika', (SELECT id FROM Parents WHERE last_name = 'Elek'));
INSERT INTO Kids (first_name, last_name, parents_id) VALUES ('Cserkesz','Misike', (SELECT id FROM Parents WHERE last_name = 'Elek'));
INSERT INTO Kids (first_name, last_name, parents_id) VALUES ('Mézesb','Ödönke', (SELECT id FROM Parents WHERE last_name = 'Anna'));
```

**KidsRepo.java**

```
public interface KidsRepo extends CrudRepository<Kids, Long> {
   List<Kids> findKidsByParentId(Parents Id);
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    KidsRepo kidsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setKidsRepository(KidsRepo kidsRepository) {
        this.kidsRepository = kidsRepository;
    }
}
```

**KidsService.java**

```
@Service
public class KidsService {
    KidsRepo kidsRepository;
    ParentsRepo parentsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setKidsRepository(KidsRepo kidsRepository) {
        this.kidsRepository = kidsRepository;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setParentsRepository(ParentsRepo parentsRepository) {
        this.parentsRepository = parentsRepository;
    }
    public List<Kids> getKids(Parents id) {
        return kidsRepository.findKidsByParentId(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. So now it should be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Spring Data**.
So you could create your own method for this purpose:

```
public interface KidsRepository extends CrudRepository<Kids, Long> {
    List<Kids> findByParent_Id(Long id);
}
```

Also, you don't need to declare `List<Kids> findAll()`, this method will be available by default with other common CRUD operations.

---

**UPDATED:**

`The program stores kids and one of their parents (or both)`

You need to do some rewriting of your logic. For the beginning, I suggest just have one parent it will be simpler to understand (later, you could add second parent and relation will be many to many).

Your ***parent object*** don't need even to know about ***any kids***. Only kids should store the reference to its parent. Also, some part of the code should be changed according to new details.

**Parent class:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Parent controller:**

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParentController {
    private KidService kidService;
    private ParentService parentService;

    /**
     * The program stores kids and one of their parents (or both)
     * when I search the name of the parent the program should display the name of kid (or kids).
     */
    private String findParent(@PathVariable String parentName, Model model) {
        Parent parent = parentService.findParent(parentName);
        List<Kid> kids = kidService.findAllKidsForParent(parentName);

        model.addAttribute("parent", parent);
        model.addAttribute("children", kids);
        // render to appropriate view
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**Parent service:**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParentService {
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    public Parent findParent(String parentName) {
        return parentRepository.findParentByFirstName(parentName);
    }
}
```

**Parent repo:**

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
    Parent findParentByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

Following you can find details for Kid.

**Kid class:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Kid {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

**Kid service:**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KidService {
    private KidRepository kidRepository;

    public List<Kid> findAllKidsForParent(String parentName) {
        return kidRepository.findAllByParent_FirstName(parentName);
    }
}
```

**Kid repo:**

```
public interface KidRepository extends JpaRepository<Kid, Long> {
    List<Kid> findAllByParent_FirstName(String firstName);
}
```

Also, I use [Lombok framework](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations there

Few suggestions about your code:

- please format it. If you use Intellij you could use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L`
- name the variable from the lowercase letter. `id` is valid and `Id` isn't
- for Hibernate/JPA or other frameworks, ***ids from numbers should be Object types***. Like ***Long, Integer***. Not primitive types: ***long, int***.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and for editing the code. I didn't understand the logic behind the scenes and I totally ignored using the Model class for some reason.. You showed me a few annotations for me that I will need to check out closer but now I've got a better understanding.

Comment: @HuserB1989 It is [Lombok's annotations](https://projectlombok.org/features/all) for omitting boilerplate Java code. Like getters/setters, etc. Don't think too much about it. Just go to the documentation and read at once about it. Try to understand the code logic. And the relation between Parent and Kid.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of kids by their parent id, you can write a query in KidsRepo as follows

```
@Query("select k from Kids k where k.parents.id = :parentId")
List<Kids> findKidsByParentId(Long parentId);
```

Comment: In KidsRepo.java I added `List<Kids> findKidsByParentId(Long Id);`

Then I edited KidsService.java with the following function: 

`public List<Kids> getKids(Long Id) { return kidsRepository.findKidsByParentId(Id);` 

Then I get an error: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setKidsRepository' parameter 0; The error message is clear but I couldn't fix the problem yet :)

Comment: Have an '@Repository' annotation in your repository class. And you can have '@Autowired' KidsRepo kidsRepository; in the service class instead of putting the autowired in the setter.

Answer (score 1):

Create another Crud Repository that retrieves parents. Then you can call `parent.getKids()` when you have an object of class `Parent`.

Comment: Retrieve entire the Parent Entity only to find the kids isn't a good approach, because parent maybe contain blob data or else.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain implementation not accept multiple parents but only one, hence you can't have two parents for one kid and your requirements isn't accepted. To implements multiple parents try to change the *@OneToMany* field in *@ManyToMany* and collection field (off topic suggestion).

To achieve the goal and find all kids name by own parents you can combine JPA Method name and Java 8 Stream api implementing in two steps.

1 - Put this method in your repository:

```
// find All kids by parent id (_ to enter into id of the parents is not necessary)
List<Kids> findAllByParentsId(long parentId);
```

2 - On your service use the repository method name and collect the names:

```
List<String> kidsName = kidsRepository.findAllByParentsId(42l).stream()
                 .map(Kids::getFirstName)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```